# Extracting Strings within messages which contains concatanation characters

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to extract messages from following type of strings,

```
Error_Message('The value 1,2 and 3 that you have entered is invalid.');
```

using the following regular expression,

`\s*(\w+):\s*(?:'\s*(?:\|\S*)'\s*|[^'])+`'

[Could be tested here](http://regex101.com/r/jI0pZ8)

But the problem is that this fails in certain scenarios such as,

```
General_Message('Sample message value :p you have '||CHAR(10)||'entered is invalid.', FunctionY('xyz', param2) );

General_Message(' The percent may not be negative.',FunctionZ('xyz', parameter2));
```

Need support from you guys to fix this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you give the specific strings it is failing against?

Comment: It does fails in above two examples,

[Check here](http://regex101.com/r/lL7qO2)

Comment: So the string you are trying to match is `"General_Message(' The percent may not be negative.',FunctionZ('xyz', parameter2));"`?

Comment: Well its a single instance, what I need is to extract the actual messages from the text. Ex:

General_Message(' The percent may not be negative.',FunctionZ('xyz', parameter2));

Here I need to extract 'The percent may not be negative.' from above string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will it always be Message before the open bracket? if so:

```
(?<=Message\()'[^.]+
```

if not:

```
^.*?('[^']+')
```

and the first capture group, see [here](http://regex101.com/r/kX1eI7).

EDIT: for the whole message:

```
^.*?('[^.]*.')
```

See [here](http://regex101.com/r/uS2nD8) for example.

Comment: actually, I'm unsure of whether you want it to be up until the . or th e first end quote or the final end quote.

Comment: It should take the entire message, Ex:
'Sample message value :p you have '||CHAR(10)||'entered is invalid.'
not only
'Sample message value :p you have '
thnx..

Answer (score 1):

I think you need this :

```
(?<=General_Message\()'[^.]+
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/fF0iV1

Comment: Thanx, But General_Message is not a fixed one, there could more type such as Error_Message, etc.